# com.sun.jdi.InvocationException in Eclipse

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

When I try to debug my code I'm getting `com.sun.jdi.InvocationException error` in Eclipse. My project has deep recursion. When the method call reaches around 750, I'm getting the above mentioned error in Eclipse. But in running mode I'm getting `StackOverflowError`.

Is it possible to avoid these errors without increasing the Heap Size?

Comment: That seems like a really deep recursion.  Are you sure it is valid -- it soulds like you have an infinite recursion on your hand.  If so, increasing the Heap size will not help

Comment: Yes recursion is very deep, around 1100 calls...!! True, increasing the Heap Size is also failing after reaching 2400 calls...!!

Comment: Which means you most likely have an infinite recursion.  You need to ensure your function does not recurse infinitely